# Java Parse Xml Vimeo - extract thumbnail url

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have the following xml file from vimeo: http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/21331554.xml

I'm trying to extract the thumbnail-medium with the following code:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + linkId + ".xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
return ((Node) doc.getElementsByTagName("thumbnail_medium")).getNodeValue();
```

But i get "undefined" as a return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast a [NodeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) to [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) so this line:

```
return ((Node) doc.getElementsByTagName("thumbnail_medium")).getNodeValue();
```

throws a ClassCastException. So you need to get the only item in the NodeList and get its text value with this line:

```
return doc.getElementsByTagName("thumbnail_medium").item(0).getTextContent();
```

I tested this with this two methods:

```
@Test
public void domTestVimeo() throws ParserConfigurationException,
        SAXException, IOException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new ClassPathResource("vimeo.xml")
            .getInputStream());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    String val = ((Node) doc.getElementsByTagName("thumbnail_medium"))
            .getNodeValue();

    System.out.println(val);

}
```

And

```
@Test
public void yourTest() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
        IOException {
    // File fXmlFile = new File("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" + 21331554
    // + ".xml");

    InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("vimeo.xml").getInputStream();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    String val = doc.getElementsByTagName("thumbnail_medium").item(0)
            .getTextContent();

    System.out.println(val);

}
```

The first throws a ClassCastException and the second prints `http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/137/151/137151977_200.jpg` I think that is the value you are looking for.

Also, how did you read from a File object passing a a URL?

Comment: Oh thank you so much for taking the time to give me that detailed answer, I will check this tomorrow. And yes just noticed this as well with the URL and File I didn't know :)

Comment: I have some trouble with the ClassPathResource, i don't know from with package this class is from (i also use GAE)

Comment: ok i replaced ClassPathRessource by URL() and it's working fine for me now, thanks again ;)

Comment: Nice. Can you post the code to load the resource from a URL? It would como handy to know it

Comment: Sure i just made the edit to your last answer, thanks again Mael i really appreciate your help and i learned some stuff in the same time ;)

Comment: [ClasspathResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) belongs to SpringFramework

Comment: Yes i guessed, i plan to install it pretty soon on Google App Engine as well ;)